# Creating an Input Accessory View programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to create a keyboard accessory view programmatically. I've set up a container view and inside that I'm trying to set up a textfield, post button, and an emoji. 
Here's an example of what I'm trying to make.

[Click here to view the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d50lg.png)

Here's the code that I am working with. I think the problem is when I'm setting the constraints. 
Couple of questions running through my mind are:

1. Do I need to set up constraints for the container view?
2. How do I add appropriate constraints to the textfield?

   ```
   override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
   get {
       //Set up the container
       let containerView = UIView()
       containerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9784782529, green: 0.9650371671, blue: 0.9372026324, alpha: 1)
       containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 60)

       let textField = UITextField()
       textField.placeholder = "Add a reframe..."
       textField.isSecureTextEntry = false
       textField.textAlignment = .left
       textField.borderStyle = .none
       textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


       textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
       textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
       textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
       textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)


       containerView.addSubview(textField)

       return containerView
   }
   }
   ```

This is the error that I keep getting.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

**EDIT**:

View Post Controller

```
lazy var containerView: CommentInputAccessoryView = {
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 60)
    let commentInputAccessoryView = CommentInputAccessoryView(frame: frame)
    commentInputAccessoryView.delegate = self
    return commentInputAccessoryView
}()

//Setting up the keyboard accessory view for comments.
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        return containerView
    }
}
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

CommentInputAccessoryView

```
protocol CommentInputAccessoryViewDelegate {
func didSend(for comment: String)
}

class CommentInputAccessoryView: UIView {

var delegate: CommentInputAccessoryViewDelegate?

func clearCommentTextView() {
    commentTextView.text = nil
    showPlaceholderLabel()
}

let commentTextView: UITextView = {
    let text = UITextView()
    text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //text.placeholder = "Add a reframe..."
    text.textAlignment = .left
    text.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9784782529, green: 0.9650371671, blue: 0.9372026324, alpha: 1)
    text.layer.cornerRadius = 50/2
    text.layer.masksToBounds = true
    text.isScrollEnabled = false
    text.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    text.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 12, left: 12, bottom: 12, right: 64)
    //text.borderStyle = .none
    return text
}()

let placeholderLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "Add a response..."
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    return label
}()

func showPlaceholderLabel() {
    placeholderLabel.isHidden = false
}

let sendButton: UIButton = {
    let send = UIButton(type: .system)
    //let sendButton = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrowUp"))
    send.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    send.setTitle("Send", for: .normal)
    send.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.2901960784, green: 0.3725490196, blue: 0.937254902, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    send.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    send.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePostComment), for: .touchUpInside)
    return send
}()

let hugButton: UIButton = {
    let hug = UIButton()
    hug.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    hug.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    hug.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9784782529, green: 0.9650371671, blue: 0.9372026324, alpha: 1)
    hug.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 12, left: 12, bottom: 12, right: 12)
    hug.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    hug.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return hug
}()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

    addSubview(commentTextView)
    addSubview(sendButton)
    addSubview(hugButton)
    addSubview(placeholderLabel)


    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        commentTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        hugButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }
    else {
    }

    commentTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    commentTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    commentTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: hugButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 8)

    placeholderLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: commentTextView.leadingAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
    placeholderLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.commentTextView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    sendButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.commentTextView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.commentTextView.bottomAnchor, constant: -22).isActive = true

    hugButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.commentTextView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    hugButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    hugButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    //hugButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.commentTextView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleTextChanged), name: .UITextViewTextDidChange, object: nil)
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return .zero
}

@objc func handleTextChanged() {
    placeholderLabel.isHidden = !self.commentTextView.text.isEmpty
}

@objc func handlePostComment() {
    guard let commentText = commentTextView.text else {return}
    delegate?.didSend(for: commentText)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Here are some photos that might help for what is happening.

InputAccessoryView working: 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBeE4.png)

TextView expansion:
[Click here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnHVl.png)

Comment: Here's a full fledged answer for future viewers:
It's not a pod.
https://github.com/29satnam/InputAccessoryView

Comment: @Dipali, How did you set the max height to UITextview?

Comment: I used your logic but not able to display the separator line. Did you face this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before applying constraints view should be in view hierarchy or error which you got will be raised. To get rid of error just do `containerView.addSubview(textField)` after `let textField = UITextField()`.

Regarding example image you posted, initial solution could be something like this

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        //Set up the container
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9784782529, green: 0.9650371671, blue: 0.9372026324, alpha: 1)
        containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 60)

        let textField = UITextField()
        containerView.addSubview(textField)
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.placeholder = "Add a reframe..."
        textField.textAlignment = .left
        textField.backgroundColor = .white
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 50/2
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        textField.borderStyle = .none
        textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        textField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        textField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 15, height: textField.frame.height)) // adding left padding so it's not sticked to border
        textField.leftViewMode = .always

        let arrow = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "arrowUp"))
        containerView.addSubview(arrow)
        arrow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        arrow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        arrow.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        let button = UIButton()
        containerView.addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        // Negative values for constraints can be avoided if we change order of views when applying constrains
        // f.e. instead of button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        // write containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true

        return containerView
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you! I am running into some issues when previewing on iphone x, how would I change the constraints to align to safe are instead of the bottom of the phone?

Comment: @DipaliBajaj glad it helped accept answer if you can :). Totally forgot about iPhone X. There is `safeAreaLayoutGuide` property on each `UIView` which can be used for setting constraints. For example fix for emoji button to make it visible in landscape mode on iPhone X is `button.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. Instead of using a textfield, I have included a textview for multiple lines. In the simulator, when you type multiple lines into the CommentTextView, it expands, and pushes the button out of the view. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @DipaliBajaj not sure what is causing issue. Do you have some warnings in console that constraints were broken?

Comment: No warnings! I'm not sure why it's expanding as well. The constraints seem correct.

Comment: @DipaliBajaj can you send me your code I’ll try to help you later.

Comment: I have changed the code a little, and included it above in edit. Thank you :)

Comment: @DipaliBajaj sorry for being late, didn't had mac to try it out. Anyways you forgot to activate width constraint for `hugButton` it should be `hugButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true`. `hugButton` should be wider since emoji won't be visible with width 40.

Comment: Ok that works! How do I decrease the title size for the emoji?

Comment: @DipaliBajaj `hug.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)` or any other font size you want.